# Use chrome.downloads API in manifest v3 Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, download

I need to create a **chrome extension** (using chrome.dowloads API) that **detect a file is going to be dowloaded** and you have to **confirm** (using a pop up or alert window) to finish the dowload.

I have been looking for a solution for days but the main problems I found were:

1. I can´t do it in service worker (background.js) because it is not possible to access DOM for creating the window.
2. I don´t know how to do it in content-script because I can´t capture the event there.

Has someone an example of something similar? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use [chrome.notifications](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/notifications/)

Comment: @ThomasMueller Where do you mean I should use? For comunicate service worker and content script?

Comment: There's no need for DOM to create a window using chrome.windows.create.

Answer (score 1):

This sample shows a popup when the download is complete.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "chrome.downloads",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "downloads"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

background.js

```js
const filename = "hoge.txt";
const url = "Download file URL";

chrome.downloads.download({ filename: filename, url: url });

chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener((dd) => {
  console.log(dd);
  if (dd.state && dd.state.current == "complete") {
    chrome.windows.create({ type: "popup", url: "alert.html" });
  }
});
```

alert.html

```html
<html>
<body>
  Alert
</body>
</html>
```